# CocoaAsyncSocket connection is broken when we trigger power button of iOS7.x devices

Tags: ios7, asyncsocket, cocoaasyncsocket

I am using AsyncSocket (not GCDAsyncSocket) in my application. It works exceptionally well in all cases except one. i.e.
When I trigger the power button of the device, the connection is broken.
This is happening only for iOS 7.x devices but successfully running on iOS 8.x one's. I enabled VOIP in my plist and added the respective code in the socket delegate method of onSocket:didConnectToHost:port as below.

```
CFReadStreamSetProperty([sock getCFReadStream], kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty([sock getCFWriteStream], kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
```

Any ideas?